# Force Karma to take updated spec.js file from disk

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm writing test specs for angular controllers, say something like this:

```
it('should have a method to add a blank category', function () {
    var controller = CategoryControllerCreator();
    $scope.allcategories = {};
    $scope.addCategoryStart();
    expect($scope.allcategories["ID-1"]).not.toBeUndefined();
});
```

Then, I need to test it to see if it works. So I run:

```
karma start
```

In a command window. Soon after I realize I need to use `scope` instead of `$scope`, so I save the `spec.js` file, `CTRL + C` in the Karma window, re-open the browser, press debug and try again. This goes on and on when I'm writing test specs.

Can I force Karma to just take the latest `spec.js` file from disk without having me repeat this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the autowatch swtich when you run it:

```
--autoWatch
```

and you can also tell it to wait for a set amount of time before it runs with the autoWatchBatchDelay:

```
autoWatchBatchDelay:500
```

It's all in the config options: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html